# JNA Binding for Win32 function DwmGetColorizationColor returning E_INVALIDARG error

Tags: java, windows, winapi, java-native-interface, jna

I am trying to create a binding for the Win32 function DwmGetColorizationColor using JNA.

According to [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dwmapi/nf-dwmapi-dwmgetcolorizationcolor), this is the function signature:

```
HRESULT DwmGetColorizationColor(
    [out] DWORD *pcrColorization,
    [out] BOOL  *pfOpaqueBlend
);
```

This is the binding I created:

```
WinNT.HRESULT DwmGetColorizationColor(
    WinDef.DWORD pcrColorization,
    WinDef.Bool pfOpaqueBlend
);
```

This is how I am calling this method:

```
var pcrColorization = new WinDef.DWORD();
var pfOpaqueBlend = new WinDef.BOOL();

var result = CLibrary.INSTANCE.DwnGetColorizationColor(
                pcrColorization,
                pfOpaqueBlend
             );

if (!result.equals(S_OK)) {
    System.out.println(result);
    System.out.println(Kernel32.INSTANCE.GetLastError());
}
```

The problem with this is the result is non-zero with the value **E_INVALIDARG** and the output of `GetLastError()` is **127 (ERROR_PROC_NOT_FOUND)**.

I have zero experience with creating C/C++ or creating binding for it. But this looked fairly simple.

So what am doing wrong?

Comment: Wouldn't you need to define the two parameters as pointers in some way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function signatures are pointers:

```c
HRESULT DwmGetColorizationColor(
    [out] DWORD *pcrColorization,
    [out] BOOL  *pfOpaqueBlend
);
```

So you don't need a `DWORD` and `BOOL`, you need a `DWORD *` and `BOOL *`, pointers to the actual values stored elsewhere.

The most direct mappings from the `WinDef` class would be `DWORDByReference` and `BOOLByReference`:

```java
WinNT.HRESULT DwmGetColorizationColor(
    WinDef.DWORDByReference pcrColorization,
    WinDef.BOOLByReference pfOpaqueBlend
);
```

After calling the function, you can use `.getValue()` on those variables to extract the returned value.

Since a `DWORD` is just a 32-bit `int`, it can be more convenient to use `IntByReference` for that mapping if you choose, to save you the trouble of wrapping your `int` into a `DWORD` when constructing the `DWORDByReference` and an extra `intValue()` when fetching the returned value.  Unfortunately there's no similar shortcut for boolean by reference, as the bit width is OS-dependent.